# Sending JSON Object from android

Tags: android, web-services, json

I need to send a JSON object from android and the format I am supposed to send is:

```
{
  "type": "sample string 1",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "sample string 1",
      "properties": {
        "fulcrum_id": "sample string 1",
        "fulcrum_parent_id": "sample string 2",
        "fulcrum_record_id": "sample string 3",
        "version": "sample string 4",
        "created_at": "sample string 5",
        "updated_at": "sample string 6",
        "created_by": "sample string 7",
        "updated_by": "sample string 8",
        "form010058": "sample string 9",
        "form010059": "sample string 10",
        "form010060": "sample string 11",
        "form010060_other": "sample string 12"
      },
      "geometry": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "type": "sample string 1",
      "properties": {
        "fulcrum_id": "sample string 1",
        "fulcrum_parent_id": "sample string 2",
        "fulcrum_record_id": "sample string 3",
        "version": "sample string 4",
        "created_at": "sample string 5",
        "updated_at": "sample string 6",
        "created_by": "sample string 7",
        "updated_by": "sample string 8",
        "form010058": "sample string 9",
        "form010059": "sample string 10",
        "form010060": "sample string 11",
        "form010060_other": "sample string 12"
      },
      "geometry": "sample string 2"
    },
    {
      "type": "sample string 1",
      "properties": {
        "fulcrum_id": "sample string 1",
        "fulcrum_parent_id": "sample string 2",
        "fulcrum_record_id": "sample string 3",
        "version": "sample string 4",
        "created_at": "sample string 5",
        "updated_at": "sample string 6",
        "created_by": "sample string 7",
        "updated_by": "sample string 8",
        "form010058": "sample string 9",
        "form010059": "sample string 10",
        "form010060": "sample string 11",
        "form010060_other": "sample string 12"
      },
      "geometry": "sample string 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I am not getting a way to compose this type of JSON Object.
I want to know that whether I have to compose an array of JSON and then put each entry one by one or can I directly get an object having this data and pass it to JSON as:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.accumulate("type", obj);
```

Please guide me to compose this type of JSONObject as I have recently learned JSON Web services, but not getting a logic to shape this complex object.

Comment: try with Gson - https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Can you please provide me a java class which can shape this sort of object and return upon getting object.

Comment: Create a class that contains these fields (type, features, etc.). The fields can be any type of object like String, List or custom object. then convert the instance of your class to json using Gson library (@Kedi provided the link for you)

Comment: @Shayan_Aryan can you please explain the above mentioned JSON Object to me. Because as far i know, json is a combination of Key Value pairs, but here things seems quite tricky.

Comment: see the answer I added below

Comment: create a model related to your json object and pass into a gson library. there are methods for different different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply this code as it is you will get exact output that is desired.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

    try {
        jObj.put("type", "sample string 1");

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {

            //creating jsonobject for particular jsonarray index
            JSONObject inObj = new JSONObject();
            inObj.put("type", "sample string 1");

            //creating another jsonobject into jsonarray index
            JSONObject nestedInObj = new JSONObject();

            nestedInObj.put("fulcrum_id", "sample string 1");
            nestedInObj.put("fulcrum_parent_id", "sample string 2");
            nestedInObj.put("fulcrum_record_id", "sample string 3");
            nestedInObj.put("version", "sample string 4");
            nestedInObj.put("created_at", "sample string 5");
            nestedInObj.put("updated_at", "sample string 6");
            nestedInObj.put("created_by", "sample string 7");
            nestedInObj.put("updated_by", "sample string 8");
            nestedInObj.put("form010058", "sample string 9");
            nestedInObj.put("form010059", "sample string 10");
            nestedInObj.put("form010060", "sample string 11");
            nestedInObj.put("form010060_other", "sample string 12");

            // now putting nestedInObj into JSONobject for jsonarray index
            inObj.put("properties", nestedInObj);

            inObj.put("geometry", "sample string 2");

            // adding JSONobject to jsonarray index
            jArray.put(inObj);
        }

        //putting whole JSONarray to main jsonobjct
        jObj.put("features", jArray);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("json", jObj.toString());
```

Let me know if any difficulties, i will be happy to help.

Happy coding!

Comment: @Safeer If this is helpful, you can mark it as answer so that other can get inspired with same query.

Comment: thank you very much, it helped me. Actually I was confused with the structure of JSON which I got right now. Thanking you a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

YOu Basically want to send a Json string to server so i think the following procedure solves your problem:

1.Add this jar to your `build.gradle` file under dependencies :

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
```

2. Now add create a class with the field names you want and that it you can convert those objects into json string format you have posted:

You can convert Objects into json string in the following way:

let's suppose you have created a model class with name Example.Java and in your code you have that object

```
Example example = new Example();
```

now you can convert the example object into json as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(example , Example .class);
```

For converting the json string to corresponding object you can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment below if you still have doubts

Comment: can you please explain the above mentioned JSON Object to me, as I am not getting to sort it out because i have only learned about sending Key Value pairs using Json.

Answer (score 0):

Your class should be something like this:

```
public class CustomClass{
   String type;
   List<Feature> features;

   class Feature{
      String type;
      Properties properties;
      String geometry;
   }

   class Properties{
      String fulcrum_id;
      String fulcrum_parent_id;
      String fulcrum_record_id;
      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

Create an instance of it, put the values you want, then convert it to Json with [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library like this:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(myObject)
```